# Extending Background Objective-C

Tags: ios, multitasking

I am making a jailbreak tweak that involves the multitasking switcher tray opening up a bit higher than normal... This causes there to be a black bar above the linen background image... How can I extend the linen image, or repeat it somehow so that it looks seamless?

The linen is in class SBAppSwitcherBarView

it is called SBLinenView

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a new `SBLinenView` and place it where you want to extend it. You can do this by using `SBLinenView`'s `+(id)squareImageForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` which returns a square `UIImag`e of the bounds you pass it.